# Fix cluster movement PySpark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means

I use `from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans` library to do KMeans clustering. I want to **ensure** that the clusters move only 10 times and **no more** 10 times. Which parameter should I use for this? For me, I think it should be `maxIter=10`, but not sure. Which one is the best? `maxIter=10` or `initSteps=10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initSteps` is related to the number of times the initialization step is to be done for KMeans. While `maxIter` is the maximum no.of iterations it will run. For your purpose, setting the `initSteps=10` **will not ensure** that the cluster moves only 10 times. I could not find an example in PySpark, but for Sklearn you can see the effect of KMeans initialization in [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_stability_low_dim_dense.html).